# XAML - How to access subelements of a listview? Windows 10 Universal

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I have a ListView to which I bind Items of Type Baustellen. Baustellen also has a property called status of type string. Now I want to iterate through these Items. When the property status has a specific value, I want the inner Stackpanel have a special background Color. (How do I get a reference to the StackPanel associated with the current item?) How can I do that? Here the Code:

```
                <ListView x:Name="baustellenListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Baustellen}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectionChanged="baustellenListView_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Baustelle">
 I MEAN THIS STACKPANEL <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="{x:Bind auftraggeber.name}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text=", "/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="{x:Bind auftraggeber.vorname}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind strasse}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="">
                                    <Run Text=" " />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind hausnr}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text=", "/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind ort.plz}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="&#160;"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind ort.name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And in codebehind:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < Baustellen.Count; i++)
        {
            if(Baustellen.ElementAt(i).status == "Aktuell")
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah crap I didn't read your tags, gave a WPF answer so deleted it, will have to swing back when I'm on a win10 machine to make sure I got my syntax right for the port of concept. You just want a DataTrigger with ChangePropertyAction though.

Comment: Ok thx, could you please repost the wpf Code, maybe it still works in universal. I Need a solution for this till tomorrow.

Comment: Oh shoot sorry, forgot about this. Ya sorry we haven't gone to win10 yet at work yet so I can only do UWP stuff from home and been abnormally busy all week. I'll undelete my WPF version for reference but it won't work in UWP.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Visual States, maybe?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not as versed in UWP xaml yet as I am others since I haven't had enough opportunities to dive into it. Would need to visit on a relevant environment unless someone comes along in the meantime. I've got a really busy week both during and after work hours so honestly I may not get to this soon, sorry amigo. I'm sure there's a property change tutorial somewhere for UWP though.

Comment: Thank you anyway, amigo.

Comment: Kein Problem, ich helfen, wann immer ich kann. :) In the meantime though, you should be able to just bind the Background property and do it in code behind, I'm just a xaml nerd lol.

Comment: Oh and I'm going to go ahead re-delete that answer so folks will know nobody answered this yet if that's alright?

Comment: can you clarify something... do you need those stackpanels to always have a background color based on the status? like "error" always red, "good" - green. Or do you need the background to get colored when you press a button, execute an action ?

Comment: Yeah, the Background Color is based on the string value Status has.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if understand you correctly. You want to change the background of the stack panel based on the value you are binding? If thats so you don't need to access data template control. All you have to do is create a converter. Something like this.

```
public class StatusToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string status = value.ToString();

        if (status == "a")
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

you have to include it to you page as well.
I have a folder in my application called CustomConvertersFolder which my converter is located.

```
xmlns:converter ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.CustomConvertersFolder"
```

Now you can use the converter to simplify your life:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StatusToColorConverter x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And finally the binding.

```
<ListView x:Name="baustellenListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Baustellen}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectionChanged="baustellenListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Baustelle">
            <StackPanel Background="{Binding status, Converter={StaticResource converter}}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="{x:Bind auftraggeber.name}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text=", "/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="{x:Bind auftraggeber.vorname}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind strasse}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="">
                            <Run Text=" " />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind hausnr}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text=", "/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind ort.plz}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="&#160;"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind ort.name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Hope this resolves your problem.